# How to Range validation integer ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I'm using validations as below.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide 10 digit mobile number without spaces and without country code (+91)")]
[Integer(ErrorMessage = "Please provide 10 digit mobile number without spaces and without country code (+91)")]
[Range(1000000000, 9999999999, ErrorMessage = "10 digit mobile number only without spaces and without country code (+91)")]
[Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
public int MobileNo { get; set; }
```

It is always failing the validations saying `The value '9999999998' is invalid.`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]{10}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Mobile No")]
```

Comment: All answers were helpful in one or other way. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 7):

The maximum value that an [Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) type could store is 2,147,483,648. You are overflowing. Why are you using an integer type to represent a phone number? String seems more adapted.

Comment: I thought specifying range would be easy on numeric that's why. No special reason. I mean I thought if I take string then it will have to do two checks i.e. length and numerics.

Comment: You could use a regular expression.

Comment: All answers were helpful in one or other way. Thanks very much :)

Comment: I'm simply not able to understand RegEx yet. :(. @Vinod's answer will help for now.

Answer (score 2):

The Max Value an `Integer`(Int32) can hold is **2,147,483,647**. So you should better replace Int with Long or String.

Comment: All answers were helpful in one or other way. Thanks very much :)