# How make the field accept only int? View? Model? jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view

What do i have to do in order to make the input just accept int in mvc3 view ?
Thanks.

```
[Display(Name = "Utilização")]
public int? utilizacao { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Ordenação")]
public int? ordenacao { get; set; }
```

Ex:
I have these fields in my model, they are int and i have in my view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.utilizacao):
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.utilizacao)
```

The user can write string instead of just int, how i put the field only accept int?

Comment: Can you post the corresponding code?

Comment: no codes why???????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

You need to use data annotation. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753977/how-to-range-validation-integer-asp-net-mvc-3) to a previous question that explains in detail.

Comment: But i want something that does not allow the user type string... if i type "a" the input does not show anything..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something that might be client-side driven, based off of key press.  Here is what I came up with.

```
$("#Utilização").keypress(function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode;
            if (keyCode == 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 122))
                return e.returnValue = false;
        });
```

Best of luck.